# Imprecise values from scrollTop() depending on scroll speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, parallax

I am currently working on a Parallax Effect using jQuery. For that I am using a JS Class.

When I was first testing the code I thought everything was working fine. However I just found out that the parallax_container divs are behaving differently based on how fast the user is scolling. I am pretty sure that this happens because the window.scroll function just is not accurate enough to use it in this case. Thats why I changed the code and added the setInterval function the change the scrollTop Variable as often as possible, but this didn't change my problem.

Did I take the wrong approach, or is there a clever way to get the scroll Postion in a "linear" way no matter how fast the user scrolls ?

I added the part of the code that seems important to me, but i can post more if needed.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/jkresse/pen/zYOrqMY)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery("." + elemCssClass).addClass("parallax_container");
  jQuery("." + elemCssClass).css("position", "relative");
  jQuery(".parallax_container").each(function (index) {
    jQuery(this).attr('id', 'parallax_' + (index + 1));
  });

  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var scrollDirect;
  var initialTop = parseInt(jQuery("." + elemCssClass).css("top"));
  var scr;

  setInterval(function () {
    scr = jQuery(window).scrollTop()
  }, 0.00005);

  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (mediaQuery.matches) {
      return;
    }

    if (scr > lastScrollTop) {
      scrollDirect = "down"
    } else {
      scrollDirect = "up"
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;

    var elem = document.querySelector("." + elemParentCssClass);
    var visible = ctrl.isInViewport(elem);

    if (visible) {
      if (scr === 0) {
        jQuery("." + elemCssClass).css('top', initialTop);
      }

      var diff = scr - initY;
      var ratio = jQuery("." + elemCssClass).css('top');

      // Hier wird der Speed der im VC eingestellt ist angewendet.
      // Es wird gechekct ob nach oben oder unten gescrolled wird und entweder + oder - gerechnet
      if (scrollDirect === "up") {
        jQuery("." + elemCssClass).css({
          top: "+=" + elemSpeed + 'px'
        });
      }

      if (scrollDirect === "down") {
        jQuery("." + elemCssClass).css({
          top: "-=" + elemSpeed + 'px'
        });
      }
    }

    else {
      jQuery("." + elemCssClass).css('top', 0);
    }

    var initY = jQuery("." + elemParentCssClass).offset().top
    var height = jQuery("." + elemParentCssClass).height()
    var endY = initY + jQuery("." + elemParentCssClass).height()
  }) //window.scroll()
}) // document.ready()
```

Comment: Could you post some enough HTML/CSS as well? So people could reproduce it more accurately

Comment: I added a Codepen example